# ADDing from the command line interface to a newly created container

Tags: upload, docker

Using docker I need to create a number of containers from the same image.

And I need to "upload" different packages to each of those images. I thought the best way to do it would be to `ADD` the packages to each container as I would do within a Dockerfile so I can commit each one in case I want to recover or replicate each container.

But I can't find any documentation on the subject. I know I can RUN and start a ssh session or even scp stuff to the running container but I don't think that's what I want to do...

Is there a docker command that does the same thing that the ADD dockerfile sentence from the commandline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this:

## 1. Dockerfiles (suggested)

Use a Dockerfile for each of the images you'd like to create. Let's say the original base image is tagged "my/baseimage". Then in the other Dockerfiles you'd use `FROM my/baseimage` and `ADD` the other file or directory you want added.

## 2. Insert

If the file or directory you want to `ADD` is available via URL, then you could use [`docker insert`](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/commandline/cli/#insert)

```
docker insert my/baseimage http://example.com/my_add_file /add_file_here_in_image
```

(and an [example in the docs](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/commandline/cli/#insert-file-from-github))

## 3. Volumes

You could also share a volume with the host or another container and grab your specialized files from there. [`docker run -v`](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/commandline/cli/#insert-file-from-github) is one way to mount volumes ([example](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/commandline/cli/#id7), and [volume docs](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_volumes/)).

Comment: Great answer. I was thinking on dependant `Dockerfile`s but was in need of some tinkering before I got the project layout right. I'll check the insert command.